# jQuery sortable `li` between `div` and `iframe`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to drag and drop items from an iframe `ul` to an index page `ul`.

Here is a brief demo so you can get an idea. [DEMO](http://www.mikemilla.com/dd-iframe)

Any suggestions help!

Thanks

Comment: Likely not going to happen for security reasons.

Comment: will be quite complicated, tracking mouse transition from main window into iframe is tricky enough( can be done),but then have to append element to iframe contents and start complete new position within iframe. Must you use iframe?

Comment: @charlietfl I just need the content where the `iframe` is to change when the user is navigating. Any ideas other than using an `iframe` that would work better? `object`, `frame`, etc.

Comment: why did you chose iframe?

Comment: @charlietfl to navigate through my site in it while keeping part of the index page fixed at all times. Should I have the site setup the other way? (iframe the fixed page, no on iframe the navigation pages)

Comment: if new to this...sounds like you are...stay away from iframes, they are just a headache when it comes to scripting....not hard to set template for common sections